# ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_2 to have shape (1,) but got array with shape (27,)

Tags: python, keras, keras-layer

I am writing a program to predict a random name based on names it has been trained on (character level encoding). My output shape is (44,27) and my dense layer is set to give 27 classes of softmax output. I still get a ValueError.

I have tried adding an axis to the output 
`(Y_train_oh = np.expand_dims(Y_train_oh, axis=2))`.

```
def model1(vocab_len):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(LSTM(128,input_shape=(buff_length, vocab_len)))
    model.add(Dense(units=60, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(units=vocab_len, activation='softmax'))
    model.summary()
    return model

def one_hot(Y, char2idx, vocablen):
    Ty = len(Y)
    Yoh = np.zeros((Ty, vocablen))
    for idx in range(Ty):
        Yoh[idx, char2idx[Y[idx]]] = 1
    return Yoh

def trainer(X, vocab, char2idx, no_epochs=1, batch_size=10):
    model = model1(len(vocab))
    model.compile(optimizer='Adam', loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
    for epn in range(no_epochs):
        np.random.seed(1 + epn)
        Tx = len(X)
        indices = np.random.randint(0, Tx, batch_size)
        X_train = []
        Y_train = []
        for index in indices:
            name = str(X[index])
            for chIndex in range(len(name) - 1): 
                if chIndex >= buff_length - 1:
                    X_train.append(name[chIndex - buff_length + 1: chIndex + 1])
                    Y_train.append(name[chIndex + 1])

        for i in range(len(X_train)):
            print ((X_train[i] + ' : '+ Y_train[i]) )

        X_train_oh = np.copy(one_hot_buffer(X_train, char2idx, len(vocab)))
        Y_train_oh = np.copy(one_hot(Y_train, char2idx, len(vocab)))

        print(X_train_oh.shape,':',Y_train_oh.shape)
        model.fit(x=X_train_oh, y=Y_train_oh)

    model.save('name_model.h5')
```

Error message:

> ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_10 to have
>   shape (1,) but got array with shape (27,)

Comment: found out the problem. Had given sparse_categorical_crossentropy for loss which does not work with one-hot data